# How do I return only a truncated portion of a field in SOLR?

Tags: solr

I have a really large (5000+ characters) text field in SOLR named **Description**.  So far it works great for searching and highlighting.  If I perform a search and there are no highlighted portions then I just show the first 300 characters.  What I would like to do is just return the 300 characters in the result from SOLR.

I would like to do this because when testing I get improved performance if I return a smaller result.  This is probably because the XML doc is smaller so less time on the wire and then the processing is faster because the doc is smaller.

I have thought of using a new field that just stored the first 300 characters.  I think this would work, but I was wondering if there was a better or more native solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is the highlighting hl.maxAlternateFieldLength (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.maxAlternateFieldLength).

You will need to define the field as its own alternate field. If you want to highlight the field `Description`, the highlight query parameters would be:

```
hl=true
hl.fl=Description
f.Description.hl.alternateField=Description
hl.maxAlternateFieldLength=300
```

Finally, to omit the `Description` field from the query result, you will have to exclude it from the `fl` query parameter:

```
fl=score,url,title,date,othermetadata
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the [Unified Highlighter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_3/highlighting.html#the-unified-highlighter),  `hl.alternateField` is not available as a query parameter. Instead you can use the `hl.defaultSummary` query parameter (available since Solr 4.5)

> **hl.defaultSummary**
>   If true, use the leading portion of the text as a snippet if a proper highlighted snippet can’t otherwise be generated. The default is false.