# How can I force Solr to return complete field's contents?

Tags: solr, field

I found lots of questions about how to force Solr to truncate field's contents (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452665/how-do-i-return-only-a-truncated-portion-of-a-field-in-solr)), but I got an opposite problem. When searching (from both - Solr admin and Solrj) I'm getting *only snippets* for long text fields. How can I force it to return **complete field's contents**?

I guess it is also about highlighters, but it isn't obvious how to get such functionality.

Comment: Before you go too far, I'd take a good, hard look at your indexing code to make sure its not truncating the data before it gets to Solr. That seems much, much more likely.

Comment: @Bill Dueber: you're correct! I used 3rd party API to get contents for records and hadn't checked this field. Now I see that this is API's issue, not Solr's. I believe this question may be a tip for those who get into similar troubles, please post your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you go too far, I'd take a good, hard look at your indexing code to make sure its not truncating the data before it gets to Solr. That seems a much, much more likely place for the data to get truncated.