# how to get summerized content in Apache Solr?

Tags: apache, solr, search-engine

Im running the following query on apache solr:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?indent=on&q=content%3Abook&fl=content
```

The probelm is that solr returns the whole content. what I want is an abbreviation or a summery of content not the whole thing. I want solr to return something like Google returns when you search something. (two or three lines).

Should I edit the query and add an other parameter or is there something else I sould do?
thanks.

Comment: Look up highlighting in Solr.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Solr Highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) by setting the [hl.maxAlternateFieldLength](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.maxAlternateFieldLength) parameter. It specifies the maximum number of characters to return. By default it is unlimited so that it returns everything.

Comment: I redited the query like this but it still does not work.

    localhost:8983/solr/select?indent=on&q=content%3Abook&fl=content&wt=json&hl.maxAlternateFieldLength=10

Comment: You should also add some other highlighting parameters. Check this answer for other parameters. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3457133/907590

Comment: I fixed it, all I needed to do was to add hl=true, and fl.hl=content to get content sammery. to controle size of the returned summery I used hl.fragsize=100 to make it 100 characters. 
thanks